# Migrating method views to class based views with TemplateView

Tags: django, django-1.5

In Django 1.4 and before, I had views which looked like this:

```python
def myview(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, item_id)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return direct_to_template(request, "template.html", 
            { 'form': ItemForm() })
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return direct_to_template(request, "template.html",
                { 'form': form })
```

I'd like to rewrite this to be compatible with Django's new class-based-view system utilizing TemplateView, but I'm not sure as to how to implement the methods. How do I migrate over to using a `TemplateView` subclass to implement POST and GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview):

```
class ItemFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = ItemForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Comment: How do I write the actual interactivity in the class?

Comment: What kind of "interactivity" do you want?

Comment: The same as detailed above. How do I write my `get()` method and my `post()` method?

Comment: I would recommend you read the linked documentation. A `FormView` inherits from both `FormMixin` and `ProcessFormView`, and handles the get and post functionality itself. If you want to write your own get and post methods on top of the already provided ones, you just write them. The methods are called get and post. You can also view [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L145) for more information.